# building '_mysql' extension error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mysql, windows, x86-64

I am trying to install via pip mysql for python 3.5.  I have found that I have the missing file, vcvarsall.bat in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
But I do not know how to modify istall script to point to vcvarsall.bat

Here is the output from install. I have tried solutions suggested, I have installed Express 8, Windows SDK, but nothing seems to help.

```
PS C:\Python35\Scripts> .\pip.exe install mysql

Collecting mysql

  Downloading mysql-0.0.1.tar.gz

Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)

  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)

    100% |################################| 110kB 866kB/s

Installing collected packages: MySQL-python, mysql

  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python

    Complete output from command 

    c:\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Arthur\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build t876fqxc\\MySQL-pyth
    n\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Temp
    pip-ohodnfbo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --

compile:

    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

**UPDATE**. vsvarsall.bat error is gone, after I put a copy of it into bin folder of VC express.

But now  I get this error

```
 cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\
hon35\include -Ic:\python35\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl

 error: command '**cl.exe**' failed: No such file or directory
```

But when I put a copy of cl.exe in Windows folder I get this error:

```
<pre>
 command 'C:\\WINDOWS\\cl.exe' failed with exit status -1073741515
</pre>
```

Where is pip install script is located?

**Sovled**

```
After I installed Microsoft Community Edition, now I have in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

cl.exe that works for compiling modules for Python 3.5 on my amd64 bit machine

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 1):

Try pymysql. https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL

It's pure Python, so you won't need to worry about building anything to make it work. I've used both and they both work very well for me.